# foreach loop prevous data in export file

Tags: php, loops, foreach, export

I have a export script that export items to a csv file. I want to export the additional images for each item on each product row in the csv file.
That part looks like this:

```
$img_query=tep_db_query("SELECT additional_images_id, products_id, popup_images
                                      FROM " . TABLE_ADDITIONAL_IMAGES . " 
                                      WHERE products_id=" . $products['products_id'] ."");

if (!tep_db_num_rows($img_query)) {   
  $imageextra2 = " ";
   } else {
  $img_rows=tep_db_num_rows($img_query);
  while ($img = tep_db_fetch_array($img_query))     {  
            $img2 = $img['popup_images'];
            $pid = $img['products_id'];

                $a = array($img2);
                   foreach($a as &$img){ 

                  }
            foreach($a as $imageextra) {

            $imageextra = "http://www.URL.com/images/". $img2.";";
             $imageextra2 .= $imageextra;
            }
          }     }
```

But when I export more than one product that have additional images the images from the line abowe follows to the next line in the csv file. 
Heres an exampe of the result. Each item has one additional image:

```
Item-A;AdditionalImage-A.jpg;AdditionalImage-A2.jpg
Item-B;AdditionalImage-A.jpg;AdditionalImage-A2.jpg;AdditionalImage-B.jpg;AdditionalImage-B2.jpg
Item-C;AdditionalImage-A.jpg;AdditionalImage-A2.jpg;AdditionalImage-B.jpg;AdditionalImage-B2.jpg;AdditionalImage-C.jpg;AdditionalImage-C2.jpg
```

What can I do to get this working?

Cheers,
Fredrik

*Edit*
Below is the complete section of php that grab the info and generate the export file:

```
<?php
  require('includes/application_top.php');

  if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['product']) && is_array($_POST['product'])) {

        foreach ($_POST['product'] as $product_id) {
            $products_query_raw = "select p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_model, products_image_pop, p.products_price, p.products_quantity, p.products_tax_class_id, pd.products_name, pd.products_description from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd where p.products_id = $product_id and pd.products_id = p.products_id and pd.language_id = $languages_id";
            $products_query = tep_db_query($products_query_raw);
            if ($products = tep_db_fetch_array($products_query)) {

//++++ QT Pro: End Changed Code
    $products_attributes_query = tep_db_query("select count(*) as total from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_OPTIONS . " popt, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . " patrib where patrib.products_id='" . $products['products_id'] . "' and patrib.options_id = popt.products_options_id and popt.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'");
    $products_attributes = tep_db_fetch_array($products_attributes_query);
    if ($products_attributes['total'] > 0) {
//++++ QT Pro: Begin Changed code
      $products_id = $products['products_id']; 
      require_once(DIR_WS_CLASSES . 'pad_single_radioset_print.php'); 
      $class = 'pad_single_radioset';
      $pad = new $class($products_id);
      $attribs .= $pad->draw();
//++++ QT Pro: End Changed Code
    }

                $product_desc = (isset($_POST['strip_tags']) && ($_POST['strip_tags'] == '1'))
                                ? strip_tags($products['products_description'],'<br>, <li>, </li>, <ul>, </ul>')  //ORG
                                : $products['products_description'];

                $tax_rate = 0;
                $taxes_query_raw = "select tax_rate from " . TABLE_TAX_RATES . " where tax_class_id = " . $products['products_tax_class_id'];
                $taxes_query = tep_db_query($taxes_query_raw);
                while ($taxes = tep_db_fetch_array($taxes_query)) {
                    $tax_rate += $taxes['tax_rate'];
                }
                $tax = ($products['products_price'] * $tax_rate) / 100;
                $stock = $products['products_quantity'];

                $product_desc=preg_replace("/([[:space:]]{2,})/",' ',$product_desc);

// Categories - just show the sub-category      
                $categories_list = Array();
                $categories_query_raw = "select cd.categories_name, cd.categories_id from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " ptc, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where ptc.products_id = " . $products['products_id'] . " and cd.categories_id = ptc.categories_id and cd.language_id = $languages_id";
                $categories_query = tep_db_query($categories_query_raw);
                while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query)) {
                    $categories_list[] = $categories['categories_name'];
                    $categories_id = $categories['categories_id'];
                }
                $category_name = implode(' / ', $categories_list);

// Additional images    
      $img_query=tep_db_query("SELECT additional_images_id, products_id, popup_images
                                          FROM " . TABLE_ADDITIONAL_IMAGES . " 
                                          WHERE products_id=" . $products['products_id'] ."");

  if (!tep_db_num_rows($img_query)) {     
      $imageextra2 = "; ; ";

  } else {
      $img_rows=tep_db_num_rows($img_query);

      while ($img = tep_db_fetch_array($img_query))     {  
                $img2 = $img['popup_images'];
                $pid = $img['products_id'];

                $a = array($img2);

                $imageextra2 = " "; # This avoid letting the additional images from lines abowe follow.

                foreach($a as $imageextra) {
                $imageextra = "http://www.URL.com/images/". $img2.";";
                $imageextra2 .= $imageextra;
                }
               } 
}

                $export .= 
                           $products['products_model'].';'.
                           $products['products_name'].';'.
                           $product_price.';'.
                           $products['products_quantity'].';'.
                           $product_desc.';'.
                           $categories_id.';'.
                           $shipping_cost.';'.
                           'http://www.URL.com/images/'.basename($products['products_image_pop']).';'.
                           $imageextra2.
                            "\n";
            }
        }


        if ($fp = @fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/feed/t-butik.csv', 'w')) {
            $utf = iconv("windows-1252","ISO-8859-1",$export);
            $out = 'variable_name='.$utf;
            fwrite($fp, $utf);
            fclose($fp);
            $messageStack->add("Feed generates successfully!!!", 'success');
        } else {
            $messageStack->add("ERROR: Permissions error trying to write feed to disk.", 'error');
        }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: If I remove that then only one of the additional images will be displayed in the export file, even if the item have several additional images.
But that might be the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, wrong way. All you are doing with that is looping through an array and doing absolutely nothing with it. After that loop, everything remains the way it was prior to entering the loop.

Comment: I must have done something wrong when uncomment it the first time. I removed it again and youre absolutely right. Its not necessary to have it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be enough of the code to give you an absolute answer but my guess would be that the variable $imageextra2 is not being reset on each iteration.

When you change a product you should reset the variable thats holding the images, which I assume is $imageextra2

**Change This**

```
if (!tep_db_num_rows($img_query)) {     
  $imageextra2 = "; ; ";

} else {
  $img_rows=tep_db_num_rows($img_query);

  while ($img = tep_db_fetch_array($img_query))     {  
            $img2 = $img['popup_images'];
            $pid = $img['products_id'];

            $a = array($img2);

            $imageextra2 = " "; # This avoid letting the additional images from lines abowe follow.

            foreach($a as $imageextra) {
            $imageextra = "http://www.URL.com/images/". $img2.";";
            $imageextra2 .= $imageextra;
            }
           } 
}
```

**To This**

```
$imageextra2 = " "; # resets images

if (tep_db_num_rows($img_query)) {     
    $img_rows=tep_db_num_rows($img_query);

    while ($img = tep_db_fetch_array($img_query))     {  
        $img2 = $img['popup_images'];
        $pid = $img['products_id'];

        $a = array($img2);                

        foreach($a as $imageextra) {
            $imageextra = "http://www.URL.com/images/". $img2.";";
            $imageextra2 .= $imageextra;
        }
    } 
}
```

Best Regards,

Jason

Comment: I tried
reset($a);
and
reset($imageextra2);
but none of them worked.
Would it require more code to reset it?

$imageextra2 is what I call in the lines that decides what should be in the export file.
Would it help if I post even more code?

Comment: Yes it would probably make it easier to help, but reset() actually just rewinds an array to the begining. You want to reset the variable that handles the images by doing $imageextra2 = ''; at the begining of the loop for each product.

Comment: I have tried $imageextra2 = ''; 
When I add that row only the one of the additional images for each product get exported, even if the product have several additional images. However, it is atleast the correct image for the product. 
I edited my post with the complete section of the code that generates the export.
Acctually the section //++++ QT Pro produce the same error as for the additional images, the attributes from  the lines abowe follows to the next line.

Comment: NP Fredrik, if you could accept it as the answer that would be appreciated! All the best Jason